# Quartz.NET trigger: run once in a specified interval

Tags: scheduling, quartz.net

I'm using the Quartz.NET library in a Windows service to run a daily job among others. I'm using AdoJobStore. Basically I want my job to be executed once any time between midnight and 1AM for example. So if the service was stopped at midnight and someone starts it at 00:30 I want the job to be executed then (only once) but if the service is started at 2AM I don't want the job to be executed that day.

How can a trigger be configured to run only once in a specified interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a custom 'misfire' behavior. From Quartz [docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04):

> **Misfire Instructions**
>
> Another important property of a Trigger is its "misfire instruction".
>   A misfire occurs if a persistent trigger "misses" its firing time
>   because of the scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no
>   available threads in Quartz's thread pool for executing the job. The
>   different trigger types have different misfire instructions available
>   to them. By default they use a 'smart policy' instruction - which has
>   dynamic behavior based on trigger type and configuration. When the
>   scheduler starts, it searches for any persistent triggers that have
>   misfired, and it then updates each of them based on their individually
>   configured misfire instructions. When you start using Quartz in your
>   own projects, you should make yourself familiar with the misfire
>   instructions that are defined on the given trigger types, and
>   explained in their JavaDoc. More specific information about misfire
>   instructions will be given within the tutorial lessons specific to
>   each trigger type.

Unfortunately the behavior that you need is not supported out of the box. You would need to schedule your job to execute exactly at midnight and then [implement custom misfire](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/5255.page). It should be possible to use `ITriggerListener.TriggerMisfired`.